# How do i describe "John swims" in OWL with Protege?

Tags: rdf, owl, semantic-web, protege, rdfs

i've found a web page that explain different between relations.

https://www.w3.org/2004/08/12-Yoshio/onNaryRelations.html#unary

but that missing part of code, i can't make any of them work.

how possible to make it works like "John swims"?

Comment: in OWL you have either unary or binary relations. That means, an individual is asserted to a class or to another individual by some property. So, what is "swims"? of it's a property you'll need an object. if it's an object, you'll need a property, e.g. "can" or something generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Important note**: your link does not show actual RDF. As stated in the abstract of the page:

> This page presents my (ongoing) proposal for a framework for presenting N-ary relationships.

Instead, my answer will show you how to define the necessary classes and properties to express what you are trying to.

---

RDF only allows to define statements, or triples, with a subject, a predicate and an object.

```
<subject> <predicate> <object>
        I        like hamburgers
     John          is swimming
```

An important predicate is `rdf:type` (often shortened to `a` in Turtle files, such as the one your links shows), which indicates that an individual is an instance of a certain class. To read it in actual English, you can use *"is a"*.

```
<subject> <predicate> <object>
        I        am a Person
     John        is a Person
 Swimming       is an Activity
```

Last but not least, in order to express that a Person performs an activity, we need to define an object property, `performs`, which has `Person` as a domain and `Activity` as a range.

In [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/Richard-Degenne/a6b9bcea8a8466c1b43d5e4187fb871f), you'll find a Turtle file that you can open in Protégé. The important line here is line 40, where the actual `John performs Swimming` statement is defined.